# Whats the correct way to echo out scripts in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use this script on a conditional statement, hence why i thought of echoing it out in the first place.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
</script>";
```

Comment: Why can't you use it in a conditional? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to not echo out html with PHP. It's a really bad practice. You should end your PHP before printing the HTML.

Comment: i want to use the the script above on a conditonal statement

Comment: It doesnot matter    end your PHP with ?> then do your html and then pick back up with php again <?

Comment: No problem. As a general practice, you should get as much separation between your PHP and your HTML again. I would never directly echo out any HTML. Variables, strings, etc. sure... but not HTML tags.

<?=$string?> get to know that format to have html with some php variables within it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n".
    "    window.onload = function() {\n".
    "        if(!window.location.hash) {\n".
    "            window.location = window.location + '#loaded';\n".
    "            window.location.reload();\n".
    "        }\n".
    "    }\n".
    "</script>";
```